# build-essential can't find gcc

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I just installed the `gcc-4.6` and `g++-4.6` packages from the same OS media.

However, when I attempted to install the `build-essential` package from the same OS media, it says `gcc` is not installed. The version it is require >= 4.4 and the version installed = 4.6.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this at a terminal:

`which gcc`

If nothing comes back, then GCC is probably not in your path variable.  Type:

```
sudo updatedb
locate gcc
```

If nothing comes up, then there is no executable called `gcc` on your machine.  Reinstall GCC.

If you do get the location of an executable called `gcc`, such as `/usr/bin/gcc`, then add the directory to your path:

`PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`

Obviously use what came back on your system.  See if that fixes things.  If it does, you can make the `PATH` change permanent by putting that line in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this works for you, make sure to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Sorry I could not finish the comment.Thanks dude, you are really helpful. I created a symbolic link gcc in /usr/bin of gcc-4.6. and I am able to see it by which command and also I can execute gcc. But the problem is still there. please help.

Comment: That's very strange.  Does your machine have internet access that can get to the official package repositories?  Also, do you need GCC 4.6 or can you use 4.7?  If you can, try isntalling the GCC and build-essential from the official repositories and see if it has the same error.  The OS disc sometimes has really old packages in it.

Comment: Seems like the package `gcc-4.6` is installed, but the `gcc` is not. Anyway, `build-essential` should pull it in. Are you trying to install it by `apt-get`?

Comment: @grimpitch No he is using the OS media.  If possible, I would recommend using the package repositories.

Comment: Uh mystery solved. That is very frustrating. The gcc-4.6 is available in the directory gcc-4.6 but this build-essential is nagging about gcc which is available in the directory gcc_default. But more unfortunately, I used apt-cdrom to add the mounted cdrom as the repo and apt-get install was not able to resolve the gcc. Anyway, the problem is solved after so much wastage of time. And thanks all for your support.

Comment: @Freedom_Ben Of course, it's better to use the repositories, but `apt-get` works with the install media as well, if it exists in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem.

```
which gcc
```

returns nothing, however,

```
whereis gcc
```

does return a path: `/usr/bin/gcc`

The fix for this is to reinstall `build-essential`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
```

Now, the following command:

```
which gcc
```

returns this:

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Hope this helps.